# Which programming skills do I need to have to write an application in Google Application Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to use java platform and I don't know what else I need to know about to write apps in google app engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this introduction](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction.html), you'll need at least the following (assuming you already know Java):

- the general concepts of standard Java web development (e.g. servlets, war files, JSP, session, request/response, etc)
- the JDO persistence framework (Java Data Objects)
- using the Eclipse IDE and the GAE plugin

However, rather than asking about skills, you'll be better off to work through the tutorial, and identify areas that you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to learn how to write Java web applications as the Google engine provides a nearly complete servlet API implementation.

First you need to learn how to use Java.  The Sun Java Tutorial is a good start.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/

http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html